# ActionbarSherlock confuses Fragment's onAttach() method?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

Is anyone else having problems overriding `onAttach()` in **Fragments** after 
switching from **android-support-v4.jar** to **ActionBarSherlock** 
library?
e, g.

```
@ Override 
public void onAttach (Activity activity) { 

        super. onAttach (activity); 
}
```

With **ActionBarSherlock** , compiler complains:

```
The method onAttach (Activity) of type ... Fragment must override or 
Implement a super-type method
```

but with the **android-support-v4.jar** file it works fine.

**********update**************

I also tried to use:

```
@Override
onAttach(FragmentActivity activity){
  super.onAttach(activity);
  ...
}
```

It complains basically the same thing:

```
The method onAttach (FragmentActivity) of type ... must override or 
    Implement a super-type method
```

Comment: should be onAttach(Activity) or onAttach(FragmentActivity) that is the question ?

Comment: @Selvin , I also tried onAttach(FragmentActivity) , it does not help, see my update.

Comment: my bad i just look at ABS source and found it: `onAttach(SupportActivity activity)`

Comment: @ Selvin, I found the same solution. Thanks. Please put your comment as an answer, so that I can accept yours

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to set the Java Compiler compliance level to 1.6
Properties->"Java Compiler"->"Compiler compliance level"

You need to have JRE1.6 or JRE1.7 installed.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't my answer, it comes from Selvin in the comments, but he didn't post it as an answer so it's difficult to find.

You need to use:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(SupportActivity activity)
```